PHP Status Indicators
I am not a developer at all but I have figured quite a bit out myself.
I have a website that shows my Employees/Users as online, offline or busy. I have made PHP Status indicators for each person with their picture and their status.
However since I have well over 90 people I want to find a way to only display who is in or busy. I have attempted to use ASMW teams, and other plug ins that do not allow me to create a profile picture using a URL. I am at a loss.
Here is an example of what my PHP looks like php?set=in
Any help is much appreciated

the pages you have done yet are made with wordpress ? edit your question to show us the code you use.

Thanks they are on wordpress and currently I am just using a regular gallery and adding pictures through the URL on one site, on another I am using ASMW Teams and adding the PHP under the photo. So I am using no code to display, but there's got to be an easier way.

This should be done with a query that excludes those that are 'offline'.

Thanks Tony, so I am using coBlocks and the query does not allow that at all. I tried using a php code and making it a short code but it is saying that the file is not found but it is there
